# Therapeutic areas list

Tags: disease

I am performing a systematic review of medical papers reporting clinical trials results and I am wondering where I can find an exhaustive list of therapeutic areas.

Answer (score 1):

CDISC (Clinical Data Interchange Standards Consortium) are considered to be the regulatory body on the topic.

See [this page](https://www.cdisc.org/standards/therapeutic-areas) for a list of Therapeutic Areas as maintained by them.

The FDA's list is [here](https://www.fda.gov/media/83082/download).